# I am passing string array to PreparedStatement ..I am using mysql , jsp and stored procedure

Tags: mysql, jsp

I am passing string array to PreparedStatement. I am using mysql, jsp and stored procedures, but it is not fetching data from database:

```
 String searchbycategory[] = request.getParameterValues("category");

 StringBuilder sb= new StringBuilder();
 String filter = ""; 

 for(int i = 0; i < searchbycategory.length; i++) { 
     sb.append( "'"+searchbycategory[i]+"'," );
 }

 filter = sb.toString();
 filter = filter.substring(0, filter.length()-1);

 PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement("{call some(?)}"); 
 pstmt.setString(1, filter);

 ResultSet resultset = pstmt.executeQuery();
```

Answer (score 0):

If the length of **searchbycategory** is 1, your program should work as expected.
The problem is you join the input string into one.

If you want to prevent SQL injection in the program, 
Each **searchbycategory** should mapping to one parameter in PrepareStatement. For example:

```
    String searchbycategory[] = request.getParameterValues("category");
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder().append("select col_name from table_name where category in (");
    for (int i = 0; i < searchbycategory.length; i++) {
        sb.append("?,");
    }
    sb.setCharAt(sb.length()-1,')');
    PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement(sb.toString());
    for (int i = 0; i < searchbycategory.length; i++) {
        pstmt.setString(i+1, searchbycategory[i]);
    }
    ResultSet resultset = pstmt.executeQuery();
```